# Caps lock doesn't take effect on all letters

Tags: linux, debian, console, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop running Debian Jessie with only the Linux console (X server not installed). On this laptop caps lock doesn't take effect on the special Danish characters æøå (I just get æøå instead of ÆØÅ).

To troubleshoot I've done some testing on my other computer which runs Debian Wheezy. On this computer, when I log into the Linux console, caps lock does indeed work on those characters.

After discovering this, I've made sure to have identical settings for keyboard on both machines:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration: Generic 105-key (Intl) PC, Danish
dpkg-reconfigure console-data: Do not touch keymap
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup: UTF8, # Latin1 and Latin5 - western Europe and Turkic languages
```

With the above settings the problem (which is absent on the Wheezy computer) persist on the Jessie computer. It should be noted that after running `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-setup` on the Jessie machine I get this error:

```
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

Does this mean that the changes havn't taken effect?

It should also be noted that I managed to reproduce the problem on the Wheezy machine by running `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` and choosing these options (instead of `Do not touch keymap`):

```
Select keyboard from list, qwerty, Danish, deadkeys
```

This gives me the output:

```
Looking for keymap to install:
dk-latin1
```

After that, caps lock didn't take effect on the Danish characters on the Wheezy machine either (luckily this changed back after reboot). This could indicate the Jessie machine runs with the above settings and that's what's causing the problem but when I run `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` and chose the same settings as above on my Jessie machine I get another problem (until reboot): my tmux prefix which I've mapped to `C-\` isn't recognized. This probably mean that the settings effectuated by running `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` aren't the default settings on my Jessie machine.

What is causing the issue? Can it be fixed or is there a workaround to rebind æøå to ÆØÅ when caps lock is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a report and indeed it is [confirmed as a bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1213145.html).

Found this workaround:

On the computer running Wheezy:

```
 $ sudo dumpkeys -l > mykeys.txt
```

On the computer running Jessie, I've added this to /etc/rc.local:

```
loadkeys /path/to/mykeys.txt
```